# adding multiple markers on google maps using Blazor

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, blazor

I am trying to pin multiple markers on my map. I have DisplayRespondersOnMap() for getting the coordinates of my responders from my Firestore database and storing it inside a list then converting it to an array after for my javascript code to read.

```
private async Task DisplayRespondersOnMap()
{
    List<string> respondersList = update.Responder.ToList();

    // Print each responder individually
    foreach (string responder in respondersList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Responder: {responder}");
    }

    // Retrieve the coordinates of responders from the server
    List<(double latitude, double longitude)> coordinates = await FirestoreService.GetRespondersCoordinates(respondersList);

    // Print coordinates
    foreach (var coord in coordinates)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {coord.latitude}, Longitude: {coord.longitude}");
    }

    var coordinatesArray = coordinates.Select(coord => new double[] { coord.latitude, coord.longitude }).ToArray();

    // Print coordinates array
    Console.WriteLine("Coordinates Array:");
    foreach (var coordArray in coordinatesArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{coordArray[0]}, {coordArray[1]}]");
    }

    // Call the JavaScript function to add markers to the map
    Console.WriteLine("Calling JavaScript function addMarkersToMap...");
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("addMarkersToMap", coordinatesArray);

    Console.WriteLine("JavaScript function addMarkersToMap called.");
}
```

Here is my javascript code for pinning the markers on Google Maps.

```
function addMarkersToMap(locations) {
    try {
        console.log('Adding markers to map...');

        // Check if locations is a valid array
        if (!Array.isArray(locations)) {
            throw new Error('Invalid locations array.');
        }

        // Log the values inside the locations array
        console.log('Locations array:', locations);

        // Create a map
        var trackingMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('tracking-map'), {
            zoom: 15, // Adjust the initial zoom level as needed
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN // Set to HYBRID for satellite street view
        });

        // Iterate over the locations array
        locations.forEach(location => {
            // Extract latitude and longitude directly
            var latitude = parseFloat(location[0]);
            var longitude = parseFloat(location[1]);

            // Check if latitude and longitude are valid numbers
            if (isNaN(latitude) || isNaN(longitude)) {
                console.error('Invalid latitude or longitude:', location);
                return; // Skip this marker if latitude or longitude is not a valid number
            }

            // Create a LatLng object
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            // Create a marker at the specified location
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: trackingMap,
                title: 'Your Marker Title'
            });

            // Log success message for each marker added
            console.log('Marker added at Latitude:', latitude, ' Longitude:', longitude);
        });

        // Log success message after all markers are added
        console.log('All markers added successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding markers to map:', error);
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error "Invalid latitude or longitude:" and my map is greyed out but interactable.
The javascript function seems to be getting the correct values of latitude and longitude but it says that it is invalid. My javascript console logs shows it like this:

Invalid latitude or longitude: 14.4129238
Invalid latitude or longitude: 120.9815481

I tried adding console logs and my coordinatesArray prints like this:

Coordinates Array:
[14.4129238, 120.9815481]

and my locations array is like this:

Locations array: Array(2)
0: 14.4129238
1: 120.9815481
length: 2

Comment: I have confirmed that my latitude and longitude are NaN

Comment: Can you show how you're loading the Google Maps JS

Comment: From what I know, a Google Maps LatLng should be either a latLng object, or a latLng literal. From what I can see from your `console.log`, it is an array. Have you tried checking if you are passing the correct data type?